# Access built-in iOS alarm clock sound in my app

Tags: ios, audio, ringtone

I'm building a countdown timer app, and wondering if I can access the list of sound clips in the built-in clock app, or do I have to create my own sound clip?

Comment: has this changed since iOS 8? Did they provide an SDK/library to access them>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app runs in a sandboxed environment, so accessing anything outside that sandbox is not possible. You will need to include your own sounds in your application bundle and access them that way.

Comment: Do you know where can I download the sound clips used in the built-in clock app? Thanks!

Comment: Not specifically, but you can run a google search for royalty free sound clips, or find a website that sells the rights to some.

Comment: It would be nice if there was an API to query for built-in resources.  This is commonplace in or out of the sandbox.  Anyway, I haven't found a way to access these either, so good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the sound in a notifications try :

```
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```