# How iOS get system ringtones list like Clock app?

Tags: iphone, ios, system, uilocalnotification, ringtone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS Access Built-in Alarm Clock Sound in Other App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524032/ios-access-built-in-alarm-clock-sound-in-other-app)

iOS has a system app, Clock. When setting an alarm, we can choose a system ringtone or other ringtones. Now I want to schedule a Local Notification and try to set the soundName as one ringtone of the system ringtones list. Does Apple support this? If can, how can I get the system ringtones list?